# IE warning: "The page has an unspecified potential security risk." when parsing web contetns

Tags: dom, com, autohotkey

I'm parsing web contents with DOM and found the following lines calling the outer script causes an IE security warning to be popped up. Is there a way to disable this warning in the script?

I'm looking for a way to do it without:

- registry editing since it requires admin rights
- removing script tags in the HTML source since it's not a reliable method
- Shell.Explorer ActiveX control since it sometimes steals focus

  ```
  strHTML =
  (Ltrim
      <html><body>
      <script type="text/javascript">_qoptions={qacct:""};</script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>
      </body></html>
  )

  doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile") 
  doc.write(strHTML)
  msgbox % doc.documentElement.innerHTML
  ```

IE says,

> The page has an unspecified potential security risk. Would you like to
>   continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.

```
strHTML =
(Ltrim
    <html><head><style>div {font-weight: bold;}</style></head><body>
    <script type="text/javascript">_qoptions={qacct:""};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>
    </body></html>
)

doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLFILE") 
doc.write("<html><head></head><body></body></html>")
doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML := strHTML

msgbox % doc.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Although this strips out the header contents, it is sufficient for my need.